# How to access matched RegExp special expressions?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to access to special expressions of RegExp patter.

Here is my code:

```
var regEx = /\[\[.*?\]\]\[\[.*?\]\]/g;
var str = '[[Hello]][[World]]';
```

I want to get whole `.*?` with their values.

So, on this example I should get `Hello` and `World` strings

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the values of `.*?` you could use a capturing group `(.*?)`.
The values will be in capturing group 1 and 2.

```
\[\[(.*?)]]\[\[(.*?)]]
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/t9dVDI/1)

```js
const regex = /\[\[(.*?)]]\[\[(.*?)]]/g;
const str = `[[Hello]][[World]]`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
  if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
    regex.lastIndex++;
  }
  console.log(m[1]);
  console.log(m[2]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple options to match a chain of characters...

1. which are not `[` or `]`
2. which are word characters `\w`
3. which are just a to z `[a-zA-z]`

```js
var str = '[[Hello]][[World]]';

console.log(str.match(/[^[\]]+/g)) // chain of not [ or ]
console.log(str.match(/\w+/g)) // chain of word characters
console.log(str.match(/[a-zA-Z]+/g)) // chain word characters
```